# When unhiding view & executing other code, view does not show up

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a problem with unhiding a UIView when additional code is executed. The code is like the following:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    self.oldView.hidden = YES;
    self.newView.hidden = NO;

    NSString *parameter = self.myLabel.text;
    [AnotherObject doSomethingWith:parameter];
}
```

The `doSomething:` method is a really computionally intensive method and takes some seconds. The behavior is now somehow unexpected:

1. oldView is hidden
2. It takes some seconds (it seems like `doSomething:` is executed
3. newView is shown

What is the problem and how can I achieve to show up newView before the code of `doSomething:` is executed?

Comment: what u want ..explain in sort..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    self.oldView.hidden = YES;
    self.newView.hidden = NO;

    NSString *parameter = self.myLabel.text;
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(doSomethingWith:) toTarget:self   withObject:parameter];

}
```

and revert me..

Comment: i was also facing same type of issue. Gr8!! Buddy this worked for me also. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    self.oldView.hidden = YES;
    self.newView.hidden = NO;

    NSString *parameter = self.myLabel.text;
    [self performSelector:@selector(doSomethingWith:) withObject:parameter afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

this will call your method after 0.1 second delay so in this time your newView will display.